# A simple nonogram

Tags: no-computers, nonogram

Solve the nonogram.

[image]
                  <sub>(Click for a larger version.)</sub>

Comment: I think your definition of simple differs from mine

Comment: I'm a little way through and it seems clear what kind of thing is happening. Nice!

Comment: "Ah. This is obviously some strange usage of the word *simple* that I hadn't previously been aware of."

Comment: By the way, should this have the no-computers tag on it? I'm attacking it by hand, but a computer program would make short work of it :-).

Comment: (I have a comment to make about the "simple" thing but will refrain for now.)

Comment: It could destroy a computer anyway :)

Comment: I'm still learning all the different kinds of puzzles.. Just learned how these work and going to take a crack at it after practicing a few, but I'm sure someone will finish way before me ;)

Comment: The comment I was going to make was: I'm pretty sure there is in fact a simple nonogram in this puzzle. (And lo, there is.)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Final answer is

> [image]

or perhaps I should say

> PSE.

I confess that I only bothered going this far by strict logical inference

> [image]

before allowing myself to make the obvious assumptions about the structure of the solution, leading to this (where white and yellow should now be treated as equivalent):

> [image]

whereupon it's clear how to get to the solution at the top.

Comment: After you had mentioned the "nice thing" in the comments I noticed the positions of the empty rows and columns and suspected a nested nonogram (Nonogramyoshka?). But you had a headstart of an hour and I had little hope of beating you. Nice, indeed!

Answer (score 24):

[Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/49672/31484) solved this, but here's an animation of the solution:

> [image]