# Your not so normal 'Who am I?'

Tags: riddle, cipher, lateral-thinking, crosswords, nonogram

This Who am I? Is a little more in depth, with a few puzzles to solve to get to the final answer. First let's start off with a short story riddle. From the story you should get two answers. One is 5 letters, the other 6.

> An old man wanted to leave all of his money to one of his three sons,
>   but he didn't know which one he should give it to. He gave each of
>   them a few coins and said buy something that would fill their living
>   room. The first son bought straw, but there was not enough to fill the
>   room. The second son bought some sticks, but they still did not fill
>   the room. The third son bought two things that filled the room, so he
>   obtained his father's fortune.

**What did he buy?**

Next up is this simple old-timer. You may have to open it up to read it all.
[image] EDITED: APPARENTLY WORD DEATH GOT DROPPED - SORRY. (Yes it's paint..)

As you may notice, the answers you got from the story are inside here. Now if you look at those two specifically, and you figure out what's important about them *together*, you'll find two possible keys. **The one you care about is the one that is not this puzzle**.

And now for a puzzle type I have started to learn, albeit [not on this scale.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49666/a-simple-nonogram) There is something important you will want from this one too. (No the weird 13 is not important, it's just a editing mishap I promise).

[image]

Now, if you have everything you need this part should be a piece of cake.

[image]

Text: Kt lhu tbsb kb gae ovzvp rvkekgmfp mbn wqyp wkbq fe

And with that I ask, **who am I?**

Comment: @humn First one yes, second one no, I am asking for the two items - similar concept as that second one though.

Comment: (ok, comment deleted, was trying to be funny after the first two sons left the straw and sticks) (am now enjoying the nonogram)

Comment: Oh lol gotcha - it's a good thought though. Like I said, concept is same

Comment: I added a text version of the cipher so people can copy it. Nice puzzle! :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Thanks for the text version. And thanks! I have been slowly growing how involved I make these as I learn new puzzles. I triple-checked this one so hopefully no slip ups in it. (I almost posted the solved crossword >.<)

Comment: @n_palum youre welcome! Just to check, the third character is a lower case l not an uppercase I right?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil it is a lower case L, not an uppercase i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> The **sky**

The crossword was solved by MikeQ, after my [partial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgQnB.png). Here is the solution:

> [image]

The solution to the nonogram:

> [image]

Quite clearly says

> 'UP'

Though there is a mistake in the row '2 1 1' which should be '2 2 1'

Here is a step by step:

> Grey represents an empty square, and black indicates a filled square.
> STEP 1: The Defo Nos
> The first step is to fill in all the squares grey which definitely aren't filled in:
>  [image]
> STEP 2: Mid Grid
> Now fill in the squares which are included in all possible solutions for a row/column. As there aren't any high numbers in the rows, then we look at the columns:
>  [image]
> STEP 3: The Rows Know the Row Knows
> After checking the columns, a lot of the rows are very nearly complete. We can fill in a few blacks and a lot of greys:
>  [image]
> STEP 4: Number of squares left diminish as we come to a finish
> From here it is plain sailing. We get the final answer (mistake highlighted in red)
>  [image]

So:

> match and candle have the shared letter C in the crossword. There are two words beginning with C: Crossword and Container. We are told that the one we want isn't the one that is the puzzle. The puzzle is a crossword so we want Container.

Applying the keyword

> CONTAINER

to the cipher gives:

> !If you look in the given direction you will find me

The direction given by the nonogram is

> UP

and the

> sky is up, so you are the sky

Comment: I think there is an error in the 4th line from the last.  It says "2 1 1" but I think it should say "2 2 1", as in Beastly's answer.

Comment: ^vote with a note: I wonder if the discrepancy in the **2 1 1** nonogram line is a clue

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Nice step by step, all looking good so far

Comment: Match & candle together, within the crossword yields _ and that paired with the bolded clue should give you the cipher

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Indeed you did, nice work :)

Comment: @n_palum thanks, great puzzle! If you don't mind I'm going to clear up some of these obsolete comments, and maybe you could do the same? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Answer in progress. The puzzle says to put them together, so...

> ... I put the images on top of each other, and got this:
>  [image: overlayed image]
>  Explanation (with partial credit to [B540Glenn's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/49707/30304)). The third son buys a match and candle. He ignites the candle, which fills the room with light.
>  The result of the nonogram is "UP".
>  I am not sure about my answer for 5 down.

Comment: Technically there are 4 parts ;) riddle, crossword, nonogram, cipher. JS.

Comment: Dang, while that would have been super clever, take it more literally. The answers I am referring to (from the first riddle) together in the crossword.

Answer (score 1):

Beastly answered 3 across

4 down should be

> Candle
>  
> A lighted candle will fill a room with light.