# Solve the ladder, but you have to get there first

Tags: number-sequence, nonogram, word-ladder

First things first, your ever so helpful nonogram. It's got what you need.
[image]

---

That should help you sort through this to get your words for the ladder.

4687043851356807498045680642604256148950054205817162311154811546033200909410247081150107615124153210302114565151011511915121049921611212105021541458901239145711501201032145101500106615015471701306380183210654818015011750561105530178981323103228041451215011520011241655001064012501156504526132621017716115151620518408406021680543214581104680585608495158410214415607062151054818766054160051912866052510

---

So once you have your words, your ladder to solve, easy enough:

[image]

Text Version: 
_ _ _ _ _ - Your first word 
_ _ _ _ _ - Slow down 
_ _ _ _ _ - Courage 
_ _ _ _ _ - Serious 
_ _ _ _ _ - Marks or Incline/Decline 
_ _ _ _ _ - Open forest space 
_ _ _ _ _ - Pleasure 
_ _ _ _ _ - Drive with a stick 
_ _ _ _ _ - Positive qualities 
_ _ _ _ _ - Forests 
_ _ _ _ _ - Communicate  
_ _ _ _ _ - Invertebrates  
_ _ _ _ _ - Paperwork to fill 
_ _ _ _ _ - Unyielding to pressure 
_ _ _ _ _ - Project from a gun 
_ _ _ _ _ - Loss of job 
_ _ _ _ _ - Your last word

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help from @Meta45, I managed to work out the entire word ladder save for the first and last words:

> `????? - Your first word`
>  `BRAKE - Slow down`
>  `BRAVE - Courage`
>  `GRAVE - Serious`
>  `GRADE - Marks or Incline/Decline`
>  `GLADE - Open forest space`
>  `GLADS - Pleasure`
>  `GOADS - Drive with a stick`
>  `GOODS - Positive qualities`
>  `WOODS - Forest`
>  `WORDS - Communicate`
>  `WORMS - Invertebrates`
>  `FORMS - Paperwork to fill` (found by @Meta45)
>  `FIRMS - Unyielding to pressure` (found by @Meta45)
>  `FIRES - Project from a gun`
>  `FIRED - Loss of job` (found by @Meta45)
>  `????? - Your last word`

@Sp3000 then found the first and last words:

> `BROKE` and `FIXED`

All that remained was to figure out how to obtain those words from the number sequence. Thanks to the hints, and @Beastly Gerbil's existing answer, I realized that

> You have to take every **fifth** number of the sequence. This gives you 01000010011100100110111101101011011001010100011001101001011110000110010101100100, which is clearly binary.
>
>  Split into sections of **eight** (i.e. bytes) and you get 01000010 01110010 01101111 01101011 01100101 01000110 01101001 01111000 01100101 01100100. I can't check yet, but I *assume* that when converted into a string this spells out "BROKEFIXED".

I need to stop doing puzzles in reverse.

Comment: probably "loss of job" is "fired", "paperwork to fill" is "forms" and "unyielding to pressure" is "firm_". However, I cannot fully get the steps.

Comment: Based on that ladder I'm going to take a guess that first/last is `BROKE / FIXED` :P (probably wrong, but I felt like saying it)

Comment: Oh, that's a really good call, @Sp3000! I'm adding that in.

Comment: Dang I was really hoping people wouldn't just brute force the ladder, but alas you'd be correct in that. Not selecting an answer until the number sequence is solved

Comment: @n_palum Apologies for breaking your puzzle :P I'll work on the number sequence but I'm still not quite sure what to do with it.

Comment: @F1Krazy It's okay, I figured it may have happened, but I didn't want to make the hints impossible so it was bound to happen with all you smart people... And my hint for the numbers is -th

Comment: Yup, every 5th should give you the binary sequence, hence the 8 as a hint, and brokefixed should be what you get. Nice work

Comment: @n_palum As a bit of puzzling feedback, in general the word ladder clues should match the tense/plurality/word form of the answer. For example, "courage" would ordinarily clue BRAVERY, whereas for BRAVE you'd want to clue with "courageous".

Comment: @Sp3000 Much appreciated! I tend to miss some of the finer details since I have just been trying out a wide variety of puzzles to create.. Few people have mentioned tenses and grammar stuff like that.. I've been making note of it to make things better in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Nonogram solution:

> [image]

So

> 5 - and (thanks @Roger) - 8

Step by step (along the same lines as [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/49705/18250) step by step)

> Grey represents an empty square, and black indicates a filled square.
> STEP 1: The Defo Nos
> The first step is to fill in all the squares grey which definitely aren't filled in (Note I missed one, the first column which is fixed in step 3. This does effect Step 2 but not much):
>  [image]
> STEP 2: Mid Grid
> Now fill in the squares which are included in all possible solutions for a row/column. There are several in each and the block in the middloe helps a lot in the rows. We can already see the shape:
>  [image]
> STEP 3: I Rowed down the Columns
> After this there are a lot nearly complete. We can fill in a lot of greys and squares
>  [image]
> STEP 4: Number of squares left diminish as we come to a finish
> From here it is plain sailing. We get the final answer:
>  [image]

Now I'm not sure, but maybe we need to look through the 5s and 8s?

46**8**7043**85**13**5**6**8**0749**8**04**5**6**8**06426042**5**614**8**9**5**00**5**420**58**171623111**5**4**8**11**5**460332009094102470**8**11**5**010761**5**1241**5**3210302114**5**6**5**1**5**1011**5**1191**5**12104992161121210**5**021**5**414**58**90123914**5**711**5**0120103214**5**101**5**0010661**5**01**5**4717013063**8**01**8**32106**5**4**8**1**8**01**5**0117**5**0**5**6110**55**3017**8**9**8**132310322**8**0414**5**121**5**011**5**200112416**55**001064012**5**011**5**6**5**04**5**2613262101771611**5**1**5**1620**5**1**8**40**8**4060216**8**0**5**43214**58**11046**8**0**585**60849**5**1**58**41021441**5**6070621**5**10**5**4**8**1**8**7660**5**41600**5**1912**8**660**5**2**5**10

The rest was solved by F1Krazy:

> Taking every fifth number gives binary for BrokeFixed. This gives the completed wordladder:
>
>  `BROKE - Your first word`
>  `BRAKE - Slow down`
>  `BRAVE - Courage`
>  `GRAVE - Serious`
>  `GRADE - Marks or Incline/Decline`
>  `GLADE - Open forest space`
>  `GLADS - Pleasure`
>  `GOADS - Drive with a stick`
>  `GOODS - Positive qualities`
>  `WOODS - Forest`
>  `WORDS - Communicate`
>  `WORMS - Invertebrates`
>  `FORMS - Paperwork to fill` (found by @Meta45)
>  `FIRMS - Unyielding to pressure` (found by @Meta45)
>  `FIRES - Project from a gun`
>  `FIRED - Loss of job` (found by @Meta45)
>  `FIXED - Your last word`

Comment: I think the middle symbol is meant to be "and". I've seen people do ampersands that way before.

Comment: Or may be we need to divide those numbers in groups of 8*5/5*8 as the total number of digits are 400

Comment: It's worth noting that there are 85 5s and 8s, which is the same number of letters in the word ladder (5*17 = 85)

Comment: @Sp3000 My hint for the numbers is to maybe think less of the literal numbers, maybe more like spacing ;) it was totally a bizarre by chance thing that the numbers added up to the letters

Comment: @n_palum added step by step. Same as previous one basically :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil lol thanks, now you should go finish the other one you started from yesterday ;) although you're a bit more than 3 hours late *wink* *wink*